# How to push to UIViewController from SwiftUI View that is in NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swiftui

I have a **SwiftUI** `View` instantiated from the scene delegate inside a `UINavigationController`
I would like to push to another `UIViewController` from the **SwiftUI** `View`

My Scene Delegate showing how my `View` is instantiated :

```
    let vc = UIHostingController(rootView:SwiftUIView())
    let navigationControll = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationControll
    // Present window to screen
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

You would have to wrap your  `UIViewController` in a SwiftUI `View` and then navigate to that.

For example

```
struct MyMasterViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MasterViewController {
        var sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var vc = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MasterViewController") as! MasterViewController
        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MasterViewController, context: Context) {
    }
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = MasterViewController
}
```

and call it simply in `NavigationLink` like this from SwiftUI `View`

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: MyMasterViewController()) {
                           Text("Show Detail View")
        }.navigationBarTitle("Navigation")
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }.   
}
```

Read more about Wrapping ViewControllers in SwiftUI [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/wrapping-a-uiviewcontroller-in-a-swiftui-view)

Comment: Although you can achieve your goal by using this way, i don't recommend this kind of mixed way because `NavigationLink` seems still unstable. I would prefer to use `UINavigationController` from UIKit as the base container and use SwiftUI view as a content view if it's more convenient to make any view you want than using UIKit.

Comment: How is it unstable ?  Would using it create a another nav ? Or its pushing on the same nav, post an answer regard this with code

Comment: So you asked a question and answered by yourself, then made your answer accepted?